# BitmapSource.Create creates two copies of image data

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, bitmapsource

Have an application which processes a number of images. The memory footprint is approx twice the expected size.

I have pruned my code down to what is shown below, the _source is an instance variable which stays in scope:

```
int width = 924;
int height = 1116;
int length = width * height;
UInt32[] data = new UInt32[length];

_source = BitmapSource.Create( width, height, 96, 96, 
                               PixelFormats.Pbgra32, 
                               null, data, width * sizeof(UInt32));
_source.Freeze();
```

If I feed this through the ANTS Memory Profiler I see BitmapSafeMIHandle get allocated and an increase in memory usage approx twice the size of the bitmap each time it is run.

What am I not doing? Do I have to live with this? Any ans all info appreciated.

Cheers,
Nigel

Comment: Maybe BitmapSource.Create allocates and copies your 'data' to the _source? and your 'data' var hasn't been freed?